# icons not appearing in the BottomNavigationBar from drawable

Tags: android, icons, bottomnavigationview

[This links contains the screenshot. It shows the dark places inplace of the icons. The shape of those places is just like that of the icons but icons are not appearing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64vpz.png)

MainActivity.java
    [private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
    mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_buy:
                fragment = new Buy();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_orders:
                fragment = new Orders();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_navigation:
                fragment = new Navigation();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_chat:
                fragment = new Chat();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_invite:
                fragment = new Invite();
                break;

        }
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        return true;

    }

};]

menu.xml
[<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_buy"
    android:icon="@drawable/buy_ic"
    android:title="@string/title_buy"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_orders"
    android:icon="@drawable/orders_ic"
    android:title="@string/title_orders"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_ic"
    android:title="@string/title_navigation"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_chat"
    android:icon="@drawable/chat_ic"
    android:title="@string/title_chat"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_invite"
    android:icon="@drawable/invite_ic"
    android:title="@string/title_invite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>]

activity_main.xml
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: can u share your code

Comment: @UdayRamjiyani code added

Answer (score 2):

Use `itemIconTint` instead of `app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"`

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```